# How to convert a list of (Char,Int) to a string with the given number of repeated chars?

Tags: haskell

How can I convert `[(char,Int)]` to a String of the Int in the second component gives the number of repetitions of the character in the first component? For example the input `[(a,9),(b,10)]` should give `["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbb"]` as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facetious and horrible answer:

```
Prelude> let replignore ((_,x):[]) = [replicate x 'b']; replignore ((_,x):xs) = replicate x 'a' : replignore xs
Prelude> replignore [(a,9),(b,10)]
<interactive>:1:13: Not in scope: `a'
<interactive>:1:19: Not in scope: `b'
Prelude> let a = undefined
Prelude> let b = undefined
Prelude> replignore [(a,9),(b,10)]
["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbb"]
```

But it didn't quite fit the specs since it includes the quotation marks in the answer. ;)

My point is, you need quotes around your `Char` and `String` literals.

Answer (score 5):

```
Hugs> map (\(c,n) -> replicate n c) [('a',9), ('b',10)]
["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbb"]
```

or

```
map (uncurry $ flip replicate)
```

Comment: And you could just replace `map` with `concatMap` if you want it all as one string.

Answer (score 3):

This can be assembled from just a few functions in the Prelude.  Since your input is a list of tuples, the return value becomes a list of strings.

```
repChars :: (Char, Int) -> String
repChars (c,n) = replicate n c

Prelude> map repChars [('a',9),('b',10)]
["aaaaaaaaa","bbbbbbbbbb"]
```

Or if you want to do it as a point-free one-liner:

```
repCharList = map (uncurry (flip replicate))
```

Is this homework?  If so, please use the homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the input is supposed to be `[('a', 9), ('b', 10)]` since without the `'`s it would only make sense if `a` and `b` were previously defined, which you did not mention.

In that case you can use `replicate` to create a list which contains a given element a given number of times (note that the string `"aaaaaaaaaa"` is a list containing the element `'a'` 9 times). To do that for every tuple in the list, you can use `map` on the list. Now you have a list containing the strings for each character. To turn that into a single string separated by commas, you can use `intercalate`, which takes a separator and a list of lists and returns a single li.

Comment: I think you meant `replicate`, not `repeat`.

Comment: sepp2k: You're welcome.  You've corrected me often enough; hopefully I'll break even someday.