# help whats wrong with my code

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replicate function help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211954/replicate-function-help)

```
decode [] = ""

decode = concatMap decodeHelper

    where

      decodeHelper (1 x)  = [x]
      decodeHelper ( n x) = replicate n x
```

What is wrong with what I have done???

I have got a list `[(Char,Int)]` and I need to replicate the char by whatever the number is and I need to put it into  a string so `[(Char,Int)] -> String`

for example

`decode ['a',9']` will return `"aaaaaaaaa"`

Comment: what are you trying to do and in what way does this not do it? don't just say "it doesn't work", we need more information than that.

Comment: Duplicates by same user: [dupe1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211954/replicate-function-help) [dupe2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210563/how-to-convert-a-list-of-char-int-to-a-string-with-the-given-number-of-repeated). Of the three this one has the worst title. You can edit your questions, you know.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few syntax issues in the code.  For one, tuples are written with a comma, so the patterns in `decodeHelper` should look like `(n,x)`, not `(n x)`.  The latter will be interpreted by the compiler as calling a function `n`, passing `x` as the argument, which is certainly not what you meant.

It turns out that you don't need a special case for `n` equal to `1`.  Just using `replicate 1 x` will give you `[x]`, just as you want.  It also turns out that your special case for the empty list is unnecessary, since `concatMap f` applied to an empty list will yield the empty list, too.  So removing these unnecessary cases and cleaning up your code, you get

```
decode = concatMap decodeHelper
  where decodeHelper (n, x) = replicate n x
```

One more (slightly more advanced) change would be to use `uncurry` rather than writing `decodeHelper` explicitly in a where clause, yielding the very simple and easy to read:

```
decode = concatMap (uncurry replicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

What's is wrong with:

```
decode a b = replicate a b
```

?

Comment: According to Ahsan's description, this won't actually do — he needs something like `decode = concatMap (uncurry replicate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `decodeHelper` has the wrong call signature. You may get better results from the compiler if you put in expected function signatures everywhere, so that the type checker can tell you where it went wrong.

Specifically, your expression `(1 x)` or `(n x)` fail to be of the type `(char,int)`, so they don't match the type inside the list you're feeding it. You need for these to be `(1,x)` and `(n,x)` to actually make the pattern match work.