# replicate function help

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a list of (Char,Int) to a string with the given number of repeated chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210563/how-to-convert-a-list-of-char-int-to-a-string-with-the-given-number-of-repeated)

how can i do a [(char,int)] -> String  with replicate not using uncurry

for example type in ['a',9] and it out puts "aaaaaaaaa"

Comment: Which is btw by the same user. Reposting won't get you anywhere. -1

Comment: And the right answer was given there as well, by two different users.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just:

```
repli Char -> Integer -> String
repli _ 0 = ""
repli c i = c : repli  c (i-1)
```

This function is in curried form, but if you want to avoid uncurry just write it in its uncurried form:

```
repli (Char, Integer) -> String
repli t = if (snd t) = 0 then "" else ((fst t) : (repli ((fst t) (snd t)-1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists in Haskell are "type-homogeneous": they can only have one type in them. So you can't ever have a list like `['a',9].

You *can* have a tuple `('a',9)`. You can also have a list of tuples, such as `[('a',9)]`. But then all tuples in that list must be of type `(Char, Integer)`.

See also: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Lists_and_tuples

But what is your motivation for not using the plain old [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3areplicate) function?

```
ghci> replicate 9 'a'
"aaaaaaaaa"
```